# Parse dns header in C

Tags: dns, pcap

I would like to have a dns-parser. I have found this code:

https://github.com/uvic-sdo/DNS-Packet-Parser

Which is quite useful and understandable. It prints DNS answer (Resource Records) using RR structure:

```
typedef struct {
    uint16_t type;
    uint16_t clas;
    uint32_t ttl;
    uint16_t rdlength;
} static_RR;
```

The answer is than derived from packet:

```
static_RR* RRd = (static_RR*) ((void*) pd->data + sizeofUrl(pd->data));
```

I have two questions:

1) How to get a name of the dns answer?

2) How can I derive a dns query. By creating a separate structure, perhaps?

Comment: You really want to have a look at RFC 1035, section 4 which specifies the formats of messages conveyed by the DNS protocol. The wire format of individual non-question RRs is specified in section 4.1.3. The compression of names is further documented in section 4.1.4 and 3.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

1. [rfc1035: 4.1.3. Resource record format](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1035#section-4.1.3)
2. code example [rfc1035: DNS client](https://github.com/junjiemars/c/blob/master/src/net/dns/c.c)

   ```
   typedef __declare_packed_struct s_dns_rr
   {
     uint16_t  name;
     uint16_t  type;
     uint16_t  class;
     int32_t   ttl;
     uint16_t  rdlength;
   } s_dns_rr;

   int
   parse_rr(uint8_t *res, uint8_t **offset)
   {
     s_dns_rr  *rr;
     uint16_t   rdlength                  =  0;
     size_t     qname_len                 =  0;
     uint8_t    qname[DNS_QNAME_MAX_LEN]  =  {0};

     rr = (s_dns_rr *) *offset;
     if (DNS_PTR_NAME == dns_ptr_type(rr->name))
       {
         parse_label(res, res + dns_ptr_offset(rr->name), qname, &qname_len);
       }
     rdlength = ntohs(rr->rdlength);
     *offset += sizeof(*rr);

     fprintf(stdout, " -> %s  %s  %s  %u  %u", qname,
             tr_dns_str(dns_type_str, rr->type, uint16_t, ntohs),
             tr_dns_str(dns_class_str, rr->class, uint16_t, ntohs),
             ntohl(rr->ttl), rdlength);

     if (0 == rdlength)
       {
         fprintf(stdout, "\n");
         return 0;
       }

     fprintf(stdout, "  ");
     switch (ntohs(rr->type))
       {
       case DNS_TYPE_CNAME:
         qname_len = 0;
         qname[0] = 0;
         parse_label(res, (uint8_t *) &rr->name, qname, &qname_len);
         if (qname_len == 0)
           {
             qname[0] = 0;
           }
         fprintf(stdout, "%s", (const char *) qname);
         break;
       case DNS_TYPE_A:
         fprintf(stdout, "%u.%u.%u.%u", (*offset)[0], (*offset)[1], (*offset)[2],
                 (*offset)[3]);
         break;
       default:
         break;
       }
     fprintf(stdout, "\n");

     *offset += rdlength;
     return (int) rdlength;
   }
   ```